# Can't add App Part / Add-in to Site Page in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, app-part

I created a provider-hosted add-in, added it to the app catalog, and added it the site. But I don't see it when trying to add it as an "App Part" / "Client App" / "App Part"

Am I forgetting a step? I'm an admin across SharePoint

[image: Looking for the provider-hosted add-in]

Comment: Did you add the app to the site yet? That would be from Site Contents -> Add an App, or the 'Add an App' option from the 'gear'.

Comment: @TedN. Yes, I also added to the site, thanks. I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: Have same question.. Has Your problem been solved?

Comment: @GennadyG I can't remember where I left off with this since the project I was working on was scrapped and I'm not an SP developer, sorry. I ended up answering my own question with references to some helpful articles, but I'm guessing you already saw that. Good luck.

Comment: Yes @AnotherDeveloper, thank You for response! I tried route from Your answer but solution does not deploy; maybe something changed now. Thank You!

Comment: Resolved! Disabled all extensions in my default browser. One of them had conflict with VS

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear @GennadyG.

Answer (score 0):

This series of articles ultimately got me on the right track:

**Building a SharePoint Online chat room with SignalR and Azure**

1. Create the SharePoint Online app and associated website

   http://blog.jonathanhuss.com/building-a-sharepoint-online-chat-room-with-signalr-and-azure-part-1-create-the-sharepoint-online-app-and-associated-website
2. Test the app in Visual Studio

   http://blog.jonathanhuss.com/building-a-sharepoint-online-chat-room-with-signalr-and-azure-part-2-test-the-app-in-visual-studio/
3. Create the SharePoint Online web part

   http://blog.jonathanhuss.com/building-a-sharepoint-online-chat-room-with-signalr-and-azure-part-3-create-the-sharepoint-online-web-part/
4. Deploy the site to Azure

   http://blog.jonathanhuss.com/building-a-sharepoint-online-chat-room-with-signalr-and-azure-part-4-deploy-the-site-to-azure/
5. Deploy the app in SharePoint Online

   http://blog.jonathanhuss.com/building-a-sharepoint-online-chat-room-with-signalr-and-azure-part-5-deploy-the-app-in-sharepoint-online/
6. Gotchas and Thoughts

   http://blog.jonathanhuss.com/building-a-sharepoint-online-chat-room-with-signalr-and-azure-part-6-gotchas-and-thoughts/

Comment: Can you expand on your answer that you found? Please provide context around what the link provides and other details in case that site becomes unavailable in the future. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @ZachKoehne Yes, that is a great idea. I'll do that.